# Project Euler # 48 Self powers in Python

Tags: python, performance, beginner, python-3.x, programming-challenge

> The series, \$1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + \ldots + 10^{10} = 10405071317\$.
>
> Find the last ten digits of the series, \$1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + \ldots + 1000^{1000}\$.

```
def self_power(n):
    """returns sum of self powers up to n."""
    total = 0
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        total += i ** i
    return str(total)[-10:]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(self_power(1000))
```

Comment: You got answers to 23 of your 29 questions – is there a reason that you *accepted* only 3 answers too far? And why don't you tag your questions correctly with [python], as pointed out to you repeatedly?

Comment: there is no best answer mostly and my questions are tagged with python-3.x.

Comment: And, again, the [tag:python-3.x] excerpt states, in the first few words, that you should _"Use this tag along with the main python tag"_…

Comment: you mean in the description?

Comment: Yes, just hover over the tag in the question and you may see it.

Comment: i'm sorry but I really can't get what you want me to do

Comment: Just use the tag [tag:python] along with the tag [tag:python-3.x] so we don't have to add it ourselves.

Comment: okay, from now on, all my posts will contain python and python 3.x. Anything else?

Answer (score 3):

You can compute the sum of the powers with `sum()` and a generator expression:

```
total = sum(i ** i for i in range(1, n + 1))
```

instead of a for-loop. Retrieving the last 10 digits can be done with the modulus operator `%` instead of converting it to a string:

```
return total % (10 ** 10)
```

Your code already runs in fractions of a second. For even larger exponents it would be more efficient to compute only the last 10 digits of each intermediate result. This can be done with the three-argument form of [`pow()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow):

> **pow(x, y[, z])**
>
> Return x to the power y; if z is present, return x to the power y, modulo z (computed more efficiently than pow(x, y) % z).

Putting it together:

```
def self_power(n):
    """returns sum of self powers up to n."""
    MOD = 10 ** 10
    total = sum(pow(i, i, MOD) for i in range(1, n + 1))
    return total % MOD
```

This runs a tiny bit faster:

```
$ # Your version:
$ python3 -m timeit 'import euler48; euler48.self_power0(1000)'
50 loops, best of 5: 9.55 msec per loop

$ # Improved version:
$ python3 -m timeit 'import euler48; euler48.self_power(1000)'
100 loops, best of 5: 2.19 msec per loop
```

But it makes a big difference if the numbers become larger:

```
$ # Your version:
$ python3 -m timeit 'import euler48; euler48.self_power0(10000)'
1 loop, best of 5: 6.65 sec per loop

$ # Improved version:
$ python3 -m timeit 'import euler48; euler48.self_power(10000)'
10 loops, best of 5: 28.6 msec per loop
```